# Is it possible get a list of all available wifi networks in a angular PWA app on Android or windows

Tags: angular, wifi, angular-pwa

I am working on a Angular PWA app. I want to show a list of available wifi networks to the user. I am not able to find way to do this as every tutorial is about how to know internet connection status only.

Comment: any solution on this?!